# FBWebDialogs add local image to parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Please find below my code to share on friends wall

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
// if we don't have permission to announce, let's first address that
if ([appDelegate.session.permissions  indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound)
{
    NSArray *permissions =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",@"manage_friendlists", nil];

    [FBSession setActiveSession:appDelegate.session];

    [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             // have the permission
             [self poster];
         }
         else
         {
             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription                                                                                                delegate:nil                                                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertView show];
         }
     }];
}
else
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   _friendId, @"to",
                                   @"text change", @"caption",
                                   @"Some Text", @"description",
                                   @"http://example.com/pic.png", @"picture",
                                   nil];
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)

     {
         //stuff
     }];
}
```

This works fine, but when am trying to place local image instead of the picture url, the app crashes

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"troll.png"], @"picture"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params)-

> *picture*: The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 200px by 200px.

So, you **cannot** pass the image data to the feed- only a link to that picture will work.

To solve this, you just have 2 options-

1. Save the image to a server, and generate the link and pass this link to the `picture` parameter.
2. <strike>Upload the image in facebook using [`\POST /photos`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/), then use its link in the `picture` parameter.</strike> - this wont work check "Edit-2"

---

**Edit 1:**
To get the picture link-

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/{photo-id}?fields=picture"
                         parameters:nil
                         HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                  completionHandler:^(
                      FBRequestConnection *connection,
                      id result,
                      NSError *error
                  ) {
                      /* handle the result */
                  }];
```

(This can be ignored since facebook cdn images cant be used in the `picture` parameter. Check "Edit-2")

**Edit 2:**

According to the facebook guys-

> 1. `object_attachment` is not supported for feed dialogs.
> 2. `picture` is the correct method to modify the image for your post. However, you can **not** specify an image from Facebook's **CDN** for this parameter.

So I guess you are just left with one option- to upload phorto on other server than facebook and use that url in the `picture` parameter.

Comment: and how can i get its link back?

Comment: after uploading photo on facebook? You'll get the `photo_id` in response. Then simply make the request: `photo-id?fields=picture`, you'll get the image link in field `picture` in response json

Comment: dude still didn't get it ! please be more specific thankfully, i've got the id from the result which is supposed to be the photo_id, now whats the exactly url i have to use as a pointer url to my image?

Comment: Make the get request to `/photo-id?fields=picture`, in response you'll get the url of the photo- quite simple

Comment: man still confused, what do u mean by get request, appreciate any example :S

Comment: I meant calling the graph api that's it. Added the code, pl check !

Comment: i tried bro, am getting the picture url, but the share dialog page is just a white page now !!

Comment: instead of `picture` paramtere, try `object_attachment` and give it the value `photo-id`; not the photo url. Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/

Comment: Ill get back to you after trying.